# How convert matrix of intensities to tiff multipage

Tags: python, image, tiff

how can I convert a matrix of intensities (grayscale) to an image `.tif` multipage.

Each column of the matrix must be transformed into an image `.tif`, after all must be grouped  multipage `.tif` image.

**Edit:**

Infact, my matrix looks like this (I give only a few intensities)

```
 132.23016 243468.60938    0.00000
 133.69370 333476.46875    0.00000
 139.01859 402385.59375    0.00000
 142.57642 250488.65625    0.00000
 146.34622 305834.59375    0.00000
 148.19623 217373.21875 217373.21875
 151.67098 650373.31250 650373.31250
 166.51741 229359.75000 229359.75000
 188.57649    0.00000 243086.14062
 201.84036    0.00000 217570.73438
 202.03575    0.00000 343220.56250
 204.74856    0.00000 225089.40625
 208.34233    0.00000 222927.35938
```

and I want to convert each column to an image `tif` (grayscale). how can I convert these intensities in images `tif` and compress them into a single image `tiff`(multipage)?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm), specifically [`Image.frombuffer`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) or `Image.fromstring` from the `Image` module. See also the section "The Raw Decoder" on [this page](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/decoder.htm).

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: Can you show us what you code you already have, especially the format of the matrix?

Comment: Why do you suggest writing a file decoder when PIL already [reads and writes TIFF files](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-tiff.htm)?

Comment: I do not suggest writing an encoder. The section I pointed out explains how the "raw" decoder works. You need that decoder to convert raw data (the "matrix of intensities", which is not an image as I understand it) into an image.